# Adding line breaks in iOS alert messages using Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, uialertview

A noob question.

I have an alert:

```
"alertMessage" = "This is my message:    1  2  3.  And another one: 5 6 7";
```

which I am displaying with:

```
NSString *asd = NSLocalizedString (@"alertMessage", @"");
NSString *alertTitle = NSLocalizedString (@"alertTitle", @"");

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:alertTitle message:asd delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
```

How do I implement line breaks so "And Another one:" starts on the second line.

thank you!

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Add line break characters (\n) to your message.

Answer (score 11):

Add a **\n** in your string literal.

[More details here](http://blog.ablepear.com/2010/07/objective-c-tuesdays-string-literals.html)